# how to find out when a person has left his finger off the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

thats pretty much all i was wondering. Anybody have a quick answer?

i want my program to do some code when the user stops scrolling and has lifted his finger up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement the following method:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

This will get called whenever you are lifting your finger up.

Answer (score 2):

if you use scrollView , it is better use the delegate:

```
// called on finger up if the user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```